# HTML obfuscation using special fonts

Tags: javascript, html, obfuscation, css, fonts

I was browsing a German website when I noticed that during the initial page load there were some non printable characters displayed on the page (like ``). As a result the score of the match can't be seen while the page is still fetching all resources, especially fonts. I simulated this behavior by disabling a specific CSS rule.

[image: The match with the missing score]

The page adds a data-obfuscation attribute and a class to each element displaying a score.

[image: The HTML]

The CSS Rule I disabled to simulate the page load sets the font-family on the target elements. The font seems to have the same name as the value of the data-obfuscation attribute which seems to be shared for all effected elements. The value also changes when I reload the page.

```css
.results-c-7kwd95ci {
    font-family: font-7kwd95ci !important;
}
```

If I enable this rule the score can be viewed normally

[image: The score rendered correctly]

Here is the CSS File

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: font-7kwd95ci;
    src: 
        url('//www.fussball.de/export.fontface/-/format/woff/id/7kwd95ci/type/font') format('woff'),
        url('//www.fussball.de/export.fontface/-/format/ttf/id/7kwd95ci/type/font') format('truetype');
}

.results-c-7kwd95ci {
    font-family: font-7kwd95ci !important;
}
```

Seems like the site is intentionally sending malformed unicode data which can only be rendered by the loaded font. Since copying the score to the clipboard also just copies the malformed data.

Is there a name for this kind of obfuscation and how does it work? Can this be circumvented when scraping data without browser automation? Technically also browser automation does not work for scraping since the data is still malformed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. This is just an HTML convenience function. As you show, it's trivially bypassed. I think the term could simply be "encoding".

Comment: You could reverse-engineer the encoding algorithm and write a corresponding decoder. How does the encoded value relate to the displayed string?

Comment: It's not necessarily "malformed" Unicode, it might just be an unusual code point, e.g. a private-use code point. Whether they're doing this for obfuscation or merely custom design is a different question… You should be able to read that character and map it to a regular number if you know its meaning. — Of course, if that mapping changes each time you load the page, then that font file is probably generated on the fly to provide a random mapping every time. Then yes, it's purposely obfuscated.

Comment: @deceze This seems to be the case. I guess they have some predefined mapping and choose one randomly at each request. Especially since the the code points for each number stay constant. For example U+E69D might map to 1 until the site is reloaded and a new mapping is chosen. The font files seem include only mappings from 0 to 9. So maybe if I can iterate over each character in the font file I can reverse the mapping. Sadly I don't know how these files work.

Comment: The font files seem to be static on the server, since they also have an ID. For example in the original post the ID is 7kwd95ci

Comment: I wouldn't rely on them being static. Of course they're going to stay available for a while, but especially given the random looking name, they'll probably rotate at least every once in a while. If that's the case, you'd either need to parse the font file and try to identify characters by their vector specification, or render the site and employ OCR.

Comment: @deceze Right now I am able to download and parse the tff file and create a custom mapping from their custom code points to the „standard“ code points. This seems to work for now but I still need to verify that it works with other files.

Comment: This looks to be to avoid web scrapper

Answer (score 2):

i found this [noscrape](https://github.com/schoenbergerb/noscrape) npm package which seems to have the same logic with obfuscation with fonts.

it also bothers me when i need to copy the location or date from the page into a mail :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31635834)